# Nested variables with dynamically generated URLs in Django

Tags: django, url, nested

I'm trying to dynamically generate a URL based on a context variable (`objecttype`) passed into a template:

```
<a href="{% url 'wakemeup:edit_object' objecttype='school' objectid='new' %}">
```

Instead of `objecttype='school'`, I want something like `objecttype={{ objecttype }}`.

I tried using the `|add:` operator and including `{{ objecttype }}` directly in the URL, but I keep getting parsing errors.

Comment: It should work with simply `objecttype=objecttype`

Comment: Woohoo!!!  Thank you.